# How to add transition to height when certain class is removed

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to add transition when class "constraint" is removed

I don't understand I've added the transtion for max-height & it's not working

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    container.classList.remove("constraint");
})
```

```css
.container{
  max-height: auto;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
}
.constraint{
  max-height: 100px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container constraint">
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1><h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
</div>

<button id="button">
expand
</button>
```

when expand is click the "constraint" is remove but there's no transition

Comment: You need to first specify a `height` in order to transition `max-height`. Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css) helps you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transition` wants a fixed starting value for `max-height`, not `auto`. It's ok to set it at a high number

```
 max-height: 1000px;
```

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    container.classList.remove("constraint");
})
```

```css
.container {
  max-height: 1000px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.container.constraint {
  max-height: 100px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container constraint">
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
</div>

<button id="button">
expand
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing a class, you can just add a style.

So you just have to change this:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    container.classList.remove("constraint");
})
```

to this:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const constraint = document.querySelector(".constraint"); // Added this

button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    constraint.style.maxHeight = "1000px"; // Changed this
})
```

Your full code would be this:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const constraint = document.querySelector(".constraint"); // Added this

button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    constraint.style.maxHeight = "1000px"; // Changed this
})
```

```css
.container{
  max-height: auto;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
}
.constraint{
  max-height: 100px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container constraint">
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1><h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
</div>

<button id="button">
expand
</button>
```